# Library for playing Matroska (.MKV) in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mkv, matroska

Is there any library for playing MKV (matroska multimedia container) files in Flash (AS3, MXML)? I am looking for an open source or similar to open source implementation. Since my MKV file has only Theora video, I am okay even if library supports only one type of video stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only play videos in Flash that the player natively supports.  If you write or convert an actual video codec in ActionScript (or even use the C to Flash bytecode compiler) the performance will not be good enough to get acceptable video quality.

For internal purposes we implemented a Motion JPEG display within ActionScript and even though all that did was modify the headers a bit and display a series of jpeg files using mostly native code, the effective framerate was poor.

Flash player natively supports a few formats

- On2 VP6
- Sorenson Spark (Sorenson H.263)
- H.264

Mostly everyone uses H264 which is the most recently added.

Comment: Good answer, but "Screen video" isn't a codec or a format. Flash only supports the 3 codecs noted. (Flash Lite for mobile devices also allows playback of device video (3gpp, etc) if the device has native codecs, but that's different from Flash having built-in support.)

Comment: @fenomas, thanks for pointing that out.  I got that from wikipedia and was a bit confused, but I checked Adobe's official list and it showed only the three codecs.  http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402866.html